# Convert an XML node to a MovieClip

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, movieclip

I have an xml document that I would like to use to show MovieClips in my .fla:

```
<linkedMovieClip>TestClip</linkedMovieClip>
```

In my .fla, I created a symbol called TestClip and select Linkage > Export for Actionscript and named it TestClip.

My code in my Document class traces the xml:

```
var t:*= getDefinitionByName(String(slideItem.linkedMovieClip)) as Class;
var linked:MovieClip = new t();
trace("linked is..."+ linked); // outputs [Object TestClip];
```

However, when I compile, I am getting an Error #1065.

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable  is not defined.
    at global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName()
```

I searched around and many sites recommended including the following imports:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
import TestClip;
```

And I included the following dummy variable:

```
public var _dummyClip:TestClip;
```

However, I am still getting an error message. When I check the debugger it's from this line:

```
var t:*= getDefinitionByName(String(slideItem.linkedMovieClip)) as Class;
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay. Try creating an instance of `TestClip` in your program to make sure that it is compiled into the SWF. Trace out the fully qualified name and make sure it is indeed `TestClip`

```
var _dummyClip:TestClip = new TestClip();
trace(flash.getQualifiedClassName(_dummyClip));//what does it trace?
```

Answer (score 1):

With the answer above, I see my problem now.

My XML looked like:

```
<items>
<item><linkedMovieClip>TestClip</linkedMovieClip></item>
<item><linkedMovieClip>TestClip</linkedMovieClip></item>
<item><linkedMovieClip>TestClip</linkedMovieClip></item>
<item></item>
<item><linkedMovieClip>TestClip</linkedMovieClip></item>
<item></item>
</items>
```

i.e. some items had  nodes, some did not.

When I use a `for each (var item:XML in itemList)`  loop to iterate through my XML nodes () the nodes that do not contain the  node fail and return the Reference Error (since there is no node called "linkedMovieClip".

If I use a if statement to check for the existence of the node, it works:

```
 if (xmlListname.linkedMovieClip != undefined) {

         trace(String(xmlListname.linkedMovieClip));
  var c:* = getDefinitionByName(String(xmlListname.linkedMovieClip)) as Class;
         var mc:MovieClip = new c();
  trace(mc);
 }
```